# Modules: If for $f: M \rightarrow N$ holds that $ker(f)$ and $im(f)$ are finitely generated, then $M$ is also finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be a ring, let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules and let $f: M \rightarrow N$ be an $R$-morphism. Show that if $ker(f)$ and $im(f)$ are finitely generated, then $M$ is also finitely generated.

The statement reminds me of the Rank-Nullity-Theorem from Linear Algebra, but I do not see how to transfer over to modules.

Comment: You can quite literally follow the proof of the rank nullity theorem to get a proof here.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how. The proof I know extends the basis of $ker(f)$ via Steinitz' Theorem. But we do not have this for modules.

Comment: If it helps: We have recently done exact sequences in the lecture.

Comment: Suppose that $\ker f$ is generated by $x_1,\dots,x_r$, and that $\operatorname{im} f$ is generated by $f(y_1),\dots,f(y_s)$. 
Take $m \in M$.
Then $f(m)$ is some linear combination of the $f(y_i)$, and from this you can obtain an element of $\ker f$, which is a linear combination of the $x_j$.